# Ruby find string in file and print result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's been a very long time since I've used ruby for things like this but, I forget how to open a file, look for a string, and print what ruby finds. Here is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
f = File.new("file.txt")
text = f.read
if text =~ /string/ then
puts test
end
```

I want to determine what the "document root" (routes) is in config/routes.rb

If I print the string, it prints the file.

I feel dumb that I don't remember what this is, but I need to know.

Hopefully, I can make it print this:

```
# Route is:
blah blah blah blah
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to iterate over each line rather than the entire file? In any case, a simple web search will provide an abundance of examples for this.

Answer (score 20):

```
File.open 'file.txt' do |file|
  file.find { |line| line =~ /regexp/ }
end
```

That will return the first line that matches the regular expression. If you want *all* matching lines, change [`find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) to [`find_all`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all).

It's also more efficient. It iterates over the lines one at a time, without loading the entire file into memory.

Also, the [`grep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method can be used:

```
File.foreach('file.txt').grep /regexp/
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to get the root is to do:

```
rake routes | grep root
```

If you want to do it in Ruby, I would go with:

```
File.open("config/routes.rb") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    if line =~ /root/
      puts "Found root: #{line}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the OP to `rake routes`. My only suggestion would be that one should use fgrep or `grep --fixed-strings` if one isn't trying to match a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `text` you have the whole file as a string, you can either match against it using a `.match` with regexp or as Dave Newton suggested you can just iterate over each line and check.
Something such as:

```
f.each_line do |line|
  puts line if line =~ /string/
end
```